# interrupt class Main, if the method returns "false"

Tags: java, exit, break

### I would like to block a Card in my abstract ATM.

At this manner, I need to interrupt the program if the PIN wasn't accepted after the third attempt so that the Main class won't execute the next Methods.

---

Is it `System.exit(0)` the optimal decision? I chose this one because it's simple, but I'm not sure.

```
public boolean authenticity(int tries) {
                if (tries <= 3)
                {
                    short pin = sc.nextShort();
                    if (pin == 1234) {
                        System.out.println("PIN is correct");
                        System.out.println("Card is active for operation!");
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("PIN isn't correct! You used " + tries +" attempt!");
                        return authenticity(++tries);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("\nCard was blocked!");
                System.exit(0);
                return false;
            }
```

class Main looks so:

```
public class Main {
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ATM atm = new ATM();
        MasterCard aeroflotCard = new MasterCard();
        atm.initCard(aeroflotCard);

        aeroflotCard.authenticity(1);  // if pin is wrong, than you are looser:)
        System.out.println("\nRefill your balance:");
        aeroflotCard.add(sc.nextInt());
        aeroflotCard.balance(); 
}
```

Comment: It seems okay-ish here, but I wouldn't do it this way in most other applications.

Comment: you can use `yourException` class that to interrupt your method

Comment: Well, real ATMs may reject 3 wrong PIN entries for *the same card*, but they will allow a new customer to insert his card and work with it. So I think your method should loop over the tries (not recurse!), and return false if the user didn't succeed at any try. Of course, it will need to be smarter (not just assume "1234" is everybody's PIN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following piece of code:

```
public boolean authenticity(int tries) throws yourException {
    if (tries <= 3) {
        // ...
    } else {
         throw new yourException("\nCard was blocked!");      
    }
}
```

In the `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
            aeroflotCard.authenticity(1);
            System.out.println("\nRefill your balance:");
            aeroflotCard.add(sc.nextInt());
            aeroflotCard.balance(); 
    } catch (yourException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In the `yourException` class:

```
public class yourException extends Exception {
// here you can override needed methods
}
```

Comment: My point of view, It doesn't make sence to override the method  authenticity() in the Main  class. It looks like, I will duplicate the same method. I don't understand exactly which Exception is necessary to work out.

Comment: @AlekseiMoshkov, you can use any classes that extend `Exception`, but in your case, better to create your class (for example "`ATMException`"), which describes all your problems.